# gRPC Cloud Endpoints - receiving auth results in API

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

The documentation for gRPC services on google cloud endpoints states:

```
Receiving auth results in your API

Currently this feature is not supported for gRPC services: ESP 
does not pass any auth results (such as user email or ID) to gRPC backends.
```

It would be very handy to have this information, so the obvious question is: is it a planned feature? Any timeline perhaps?